# How to fix this MVC website error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

My website was working perfect but i have to reinstall my "Visual Studio 2015 Community" then every time i try to run my website or open "CSHTML" file with my browser i have an error it's title is "Configuration Error"

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

the parser error message

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

this is the red line in the error source

```
 <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Finally this a print screen of the error [print screen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmSyw.png)

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding a reference to this library?

Comment: no i did not try that

Comment: You probably should